# Query TaffyDB - Query undefined column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, taffydb

I am using TaffyDB as a local database for caching data locally and querying easily.

I have an object where some of the properties are undefined. How could I query that object where a column is undefined?

The main idea is I want to remove all temporary objects added to TaffyDB locally when the user decides to cancel saving. So I need to go through the records where serevrId is undefined, hence not yet saved into the server, and remove them.

```
projects_db({serverId: {"===": "undefined"}}).get()
projects_db({serverId: {"==": "undefined"}}).get()
projects_db({serverId: {"===": undefined}}).get()
projects_db({serverId: {"==": undefined}}).get()
projects_db({serverId: undefined}).get()
projects_db({serverId: "undefined"}).get()
```

None of the above works!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
projects_db().filter(function(){
    return typeof this.serverId === 'undefined';
}).get();
```

Or maybe have a look at 'isUndefined' : http://www.taffydb.com/writingqueries

Regards